# Web scraping Twitter pages Using Python

Tags: python, web-scraping

Using my twitter developer credentials I get twitter API from news channels. Now I want to access the source of the news using URL embedded with twitter API data.
I try to get using BeautifulSoup and requests to get content of the twitter page.
But continuously I got an error 'We've detected that JavaScript is disabled in your browser. Would you like to proceed to legacy Twitter?'
I cleaned the browser and try to use every browser. But got the same response. Please help to solve this problem.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = 'https://twitter.com/i/web/status/1283691878588784642'
# get contents from url

content = requests.get(url).content

# get soup
soup = BeautifulSoup(content,'lxml')
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you get the error 'We've detected that JavaScript is disabled in your browser. Would you like to proceed to legacy Twitter?' when running the script or when visiting it with your GUI web browser?
Have you tried getting your data through legacy?

If you get this error when running the script, there is nothig you can do like clearing browser cache, etc. The only way to get around this problem is to find another way to access the Twitter page in your python program.

From my experience I would say that the easiest way around this problem is to use gecko driver with FireFox. So Twitter gets all the features it needs.

Comment: Thank you ,but still couldn't found solution for this matter

Comment: Did gecko driver throw the same error or a different?